# Javascript: master checkbox to control all checkboxes in a table column

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 checkboxes. One of them is the header for all checkboxes. If I check the header checkbox, all should check automatically, and if I uncheck it, all should uncheck. If I uncheck any of the child checkboxes, the header should automatically uncheck.

My code is like this:

```
<html>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
              function checkAll()
              {

                if(pp_checkall.checked==true) 
                {
                    for (i = 1; i <= pp_check.length; i++)
                     pp_check[i].checked = true ;
                }
              else
                {
                    for (i = 1; i <= pp_check.length; i++)
                    pp_check[i].checked = false ;
                }
              }

</script>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
             function checkOne()
               {
                for (i = 1; i <= pp_check.length; i++)
                 {  
                  if(pp_check[i].checked==false)
                  {
                    pp_checkall.checked = false ;
                  }
                }
              }

              </script> 

<body>
<table>
<tr><th width="1px"><input type="checkbox" text="Dharan" name="pp_checkall" onclick="checkAll();"></th></tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr> <input type="checkbox" name="pp_check" value="1" onclick="checkOne();"></tr>
<!--<tr> <input type="checkbox" name="pp_check" value="2" onclick="checkOne();"></tr>
<tr> <input type="checkbox" name="pp_check" value="3" onclick="checkOne();"></tr>
<tr> <input type="checkbox" name="pp_check" value="4" onclick="checkOne();"></tr> -->
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Its working fine too, but in some cases only one `<td>` checkbox will appear, which stops the code from working. Please give some solution to solve this.

Comment: Don't know if it helps but you've missed the `<td>` tags in your table.

Comment: Did you tried running that loop from `i = 0` ?

Comment: If you used the JQuery library setting a bunch of checkboxes would be as easy as $('input[name=pp_check]').attr('checked', true); There are also other javascript libraries like dojo.

Comment: Actually this checkbox count will be increase or decrease according to the for loop with some conditions i have executed., so there is no need to set pp_check.length.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        var pp_check = document.getElementsByName('pp_check');
        var pp_checkall = document.getElementsByName('pp_checkall')[0];

        function checkAll() {
            if (pp_checkall.checked == true) {
                for (i = 0; i < pp_check.length; i++)
                    pp_check[i].checked = true;
            }
            else {
                for (i = 0; i < pp_check.length; i++)
                    pp_check[i].checked = false;
            }
        }

        function checkOne() {
            var pp_check = document.getElementsByName('pp_check');
            for (i = 0; i < pp_check.length; i++) {
                if (pp_check[i].checked == false)
                    pp_checkall.checked = false;
            }
        }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for the same.

```
    $('input[name="pp_checkall"]').change(function () {
        $('input[name=pp_check]').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    $('input[name="pp_check"]').change(function () {
        $('input[name="pp_checkall"]').prop(
          'checked', 
          $('input[name=pp_check]:not(:checked)').length === 0 ? true : false 
        );
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gPeh8/1/

Comment: I just gave the code in notepad++ and saved with .htm extension. But not working

Comment: can you give me the solution??

Comment: Unless you share the code, I would not know why its not working for you. So copy the entire code in your .html file and put it on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: as expected you had not included jquery.js into your webpage. Check the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/RE6Ta/2/